# Line-breaking two equations within equation array

Tags: equations, eqnarray

I have the code

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    &&\nonumber
    \left.\begin{array}{l}
        & \textbf{E}_{\textrm{tr}}  (x,y,z)= \left(\ts \textbf{s} + \tp \textbf{p}_+\right) \, \exp\lec{i   {\ko} \les\left({x\cos\psi+y\sin\psi}\right)\sin\theta_{\rm inc}+(z-N  P )   \cos \theta_{\rm inc}\ris }\ric
        \\[5pt]
        \textbf{H}_{\textrm{tr}} (x,y,z) = 
        \eta_0^{-1}\left(\ts \textbf{p}_+ - \tp \textbf{s}\right)
        \, \exp\lec{i   {\ko} \les\left({x\cos\psi+y\sin\psi}\right)\sin\theta_{\rm inc} +(z-N P)   \cos \theta_{\rm inc}\ris
        }\ric
    \end{array}\right\}\,,
    \\[5pt]
    &&
    \qquad\qquad\qquad z>N P \,.
\end{eqnarray}
```

which produces the output

[image]

No matter what I try, I cannot get this to render more nicely. I would like for each equation to break after the plus sign, and for the equation number to appear to the right of the bracket.

Comment: where is defined \lec, \ts, \ko, etc?. Please provide MWE not just code fragment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make your code compilable, I had to come up with emergency definitions of `\ts`, `\tp`, `\ko`, `\ric`, `\ris`, `\lec`, and `\les`.

I've also simplified your code by replacing the `eqnarray` environment with a far more flexible `aligned` environment and by getting rid of all interior `\left` and `\right` sizing directives. (Hint: they do nothing except mess up the horizontal spacing.) Next, I replaced the 4 instances of `\textbf` with `\mathbf`. Finally, I would state `z>N P` in ordinary, i.e., inline, math on a line following the displayed equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
%% check if the following definitions are appropriate
\providecommand\ts{t_s}
\providecommand\tp{t_p}
\providecommand\ko{k_0}
\providecommand\lec{\bigl\{}
\providecommand\ric{\bigr\}}
\providecommand\les{\bigl[}
\providecommand\ris{\bigr]}
\newcommand\minc{{\mathrm{inc}}}
\newcommand\mtr{{\mathrm{tr}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left.\begin{array}{@{}l}
\begin{aligned}
\textbf{E}_\mtr (x,y,z)
    &= (\ts \mathbf{s} + \tp \mathbf{p}_+)  
      \exp\lec i \ko \les({x\cos\psi+y\sin\psi})\sin\theta_\minc \\
    &\qquad+(z-N P ) \cos \theta_\minc\ris \ric
    \\[\jot]
\textbf{H}_\mtr (x,y,z) 
    &= \eta_0^{-1}(\ts \mathbf{p}_+ - \tp \mathbf{s})
      \exp\lec i \ko \les({x\cos\psi+y\sin\psi})\sin\theta_\minc \\
    &\qquad+(z-N P) \cos \theta_\minc\ris\ric
\end{aligned}
\end{array}\right\}
\end{equation} 
and $z>N P$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would write your equation as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{gather}
\begin{rcases}
    \bm{E}_{\mathrm{tr}}(x,y,z) = \left(t_s\bm{s} + t_p \bm{p}_{+}\right) A(\psi,\theta)  &   \\
    \bm{E}_{\mathrm{tr}}(x,y,z) = \eta_0^{-1}\left(t_s\bm{p}_{+} - t_p \bm{s}\right) A(\psi,\theta)  
\end{rcases}   
\shortintertext{where}
A(\psi,\theta) = \exp\Bigl\{i k_o\bigl[(x\cos\psi + y\sin\psi)\sin\theta_{\mathrm{inc}} +
                       (z - NP)\cos\theta_{\mathrm{inc}}\bigr]\Bigr\}
    ,\quad    z > N P ,  \notag
    \end{gather} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely use a shorthand for the long repeated part in the two equations. I'd also avoid the big brace, because the equation number midway will help readers in knowing that the number refers to both.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  &\begin{alignedat}{2}
    &\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{tr}}&&(x,y,z)
    = (t_s \mathbf{s} + t_p \mathbf{p}_+)f(x,y,z)
   \\
    &\mathbf{H}_{\mathrm{tr}}&&(x,y,z)
    = \eta_0^{-1}(t_s\mathbf{p}_+ - t_p\mathbf{s})f(x,y,z)
  \end{alignedat}
  \\
  & f(x,y,z)=
    \exp\{ik_0 [(x\cos\psi+y\sin\psi)\sin\theta_{\mathrm{inc}}+(z-NP)\cos\theta_{\mathrm{inc}}]\},
    \notag
  \\
  &z>NP. \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I prefer to leave a small gap between **E**<sub>tr</sub> and the parenthesis rather than a hole in front of the **E**.

Note that the input has been simplified a lot, without useless braces and the obfuscation given by `\tp`, `\ts`, `\ric` and so on.

[image]

If you really want the big brace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  &
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\!\! % alignment tricks
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    &\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{tr}}&&(x,y,z)
    = (t_s \mathbf{s} + t_p \mathbf{p}_+)f(x,y,z)
   \\
    &\mathbf{H}_{\mathrm{tr}}&&(x,y,z)
    = \eta_0^{-1}(t_s\mathbf{p}_+ - t_p\mathbf{s})f(x,y,z)
  \end{alignedat}
  \right\rbrace,
  \\
  & f(x,y,z)=
    \exp\{ik_0 [(x\cos\psi+y\sin\psi)\sin\theta_{\mathrm{inc}}+(z-NP)\cos\theta_{\mathrm{inc}}]\},
    \notag
  \\
  &z>NP. \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware that `\textbf` in equations is generally wrong and that `\rm` has been deprecated for 30 years.